# Julia error while computing powers of a complex number

Tags: julia

I'm a beginner at Julia and am using it to compute the power of a complex number as a subroutine in a larger scientific task where I run

`array = [1im^(i-j) for i in 1:5, j in 1:5]`

but I get the following `DomainError` :

```
DomainError with -1:
Cannot raise an integer x to a negative power -1.
Convert input to float.
```

Particularly, when I run the for loop and print the value for each `(i,j)`, the same error occurs at (i=2,j=1). I'll be very grateful if someone can help me with this. What seems to be wrong with my code? How can I overcome this error?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a float as a base like this (this is what the error message recommends you to do):

```
julia> [(1.0im)^(i-j) for i in 1:5, j in 1:5]
5×5 Matrix{ComplexF64}:
  1.0+0.0im   0.0-1.0im  -1.0-0.0im  -0.0+1.0im   1.0+0.0im
  0.0+1.0im   1.0+0.0im   0.0-1.0im  -1.0-0.0im  -0.0+1.0im
 -1.0+0.0im   0.0+1.0im   1.0+0.0im   0.0-1.0im  -1.0-0.0im
 -0.0-1.0im  -1.0+0.0im   0.0+1.0im   1.0+0.0im   0.0-1.0im
  1.0-0.0im  -0.0-1.0im  -1.0+0.0im   0.0+1.0im   1.0+0.0im
```

or like this

```
julia> [float(im)^(i-j) for i in 1:5, j in 1:5]
5×5 Matrix{ComplexF64}:
  1.0+0.0im   0.0-1.0im  -1.0-0.0im  -0.0+1.0im   1.0+0.0im
  0.0+1.0im   1.0+0.0im   0.0-1.0im  -1.0-0.0im  -0.0+1.0im
 -1.0+0.0im   0.0+1.0im   1.0+0.0im   0.0-1.0im  -1.0-0.0im
 -0.0-1.0im  -1.0+0.0im   0.0+1.0im   1.0+0.0im   0.0-1.0im
  1.0-0.0im  -0.0-1.0im  -1.0+0.0im   0.0+1.0im   1.0+0.0im
```

The error follows from this definition:

```
^(z::Complex{<:Integer}, n::Integer) = power_by_squaring(z,n) # DomainError for n<0
```

Comment: Do you know why `1im^-1` works (returning `0.0 - 1.0im`), but `1im^(1-2)` errors? Is there some type of hidden conversion to float that can take place when `-1` is provided as a literal but not when it's the result of an `Int` expression?

Comment: it is because `im^-1` is a compile time constant (so it is computed at compilation time), while `im^(2-1)` is evaluated at run time. Now the issue is that Julia tries to be type stable here. `im^-1` is evaluated at compile time so its type is known when things are compiled and can be properly propagated. However allowing `im^(2-1)` evaluated at run time would mean that there would be type instability thus Julia designers decided to disallow it. It is essentially the same reason why `sqrt(-1)` throws an error. But I agree that with negative powers it is a bit confusing.